# php info file no longer working after installing phpMyadmin

Tags: php, linux, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

Sorry, I've seen questions similiar to this being asked before, however I could find one that is specific to my case! 
So I'm trying to install LAMP and phpmyadmin on ubuntu16.
After installing lamp, everything is working fine. However I followed these instructions, trying to get phpmyadmin to work.

[followed this instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Plt0n.png)
Right afterward, [i got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmCWU.png).

Now php info file no longer works when i try to go to localhost/info.php
the only thing that shows up is the scrips and not

Comment: Try taking it out and see if that fixes it

Comment: Have you updated index.php file in HTML folder ? It's must setting, one value I don't exactly remember the variable but it needs to alter from true to false or false to true. If you don't did this open file and check once, alter and try running your program.

Comment: You might get better response to your question on (ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). StackOverflow is for programming questions.